# Reading metadata of mp3 file in Java - file not found exception

Tags: java, mp3, filereader

Well, my code is as below. I'd like to know why there's always an exception. The mp3 file is in the same directory as the test.java file. What am I doing wrong? Also, how do I read mp3 files from say my Music Library : path - Libraries\Music

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.ID3v1;    
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.InvalidDataException;
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File;
import com.mpatric.mp3agic.UnsupportedTagException;
public class test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
     Mp3File mp3file = null;
    try {
        mp3file = new Mp3File("dom.mp3");
    } catch (UnsupportedTagException | InvalidDataException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
        if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
          ID3v1 id3v1Tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
          System.out.println("Track: " + id3v1Tag.getTrack());
          System.out.println("Artist: " + id3v1Tag.getArtist());
          System.out.println("Title: " + id3v1Tag.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Album: " + id3v1Tag.getAlbum());
          System.out.println("Year: " + id3v1Tag.getYear());
          System.out.println("Genre: " + id3v1Tag.getGenre() + " (" + id3v1Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")");
          System.out.println("Comment: " + id3v1Tag.getComment());
        }
}
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found dom.mp3
at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.init(FileWrapper.java:26)
at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.<init>(FileWrapper.java:19)
at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:53)
at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:41)
at test.main(test.java:13)
File not found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at test.main(test.java:19)
```

The mpatric package is 3rd party. I'm guessing that works fine.

What do you mean by "same directory as you run your java process from"? Can you give me a for instance, please?

Comment: Try putting your mp3 file in your classpath as a matter of fact what is classpath http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Comment: Yeah, the class is in the bin folder. I put the mp3 file there, a null pointer exception is still thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); Pasted that into my code, found out the root dir. Apparently it's on the same level as the src and bin folders. Pasted the file there and it works like a charm now.

Alright, if anyone was wondering if you can change the home directory, you can't.

If you want to access another folder, you'll have to resort to directory traversal. Say your music file "Ride the Lightning.mp3" is in C:\Users\"Your Username"\Music\

Then to read that you'll have to do something like this:

```
mp3file = new Mp3File("../../../Music/Misc/Ride the Lightning.mp3");
```

Cheers to Brian and Chasmo for the helpful posts.

Comment: But this gives you your home directory? Not your root folder of your project.

Comment: I think this is a bad solution. You could try something else. I will update my code above. If you think it will help, please mark it as solved ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Printing this:

```
  System.out.println("File not found.");
```

is misleading, given this:

```
catch (UnsupportedTagException | InvalidDataException | IOException e)
```

You need to dump the exception (`e.printStackTrace()` to determine the real issue).

Your `.mp3` file is in the same directory as your `.java` file. But that's not relevant. Is it in the same directory as where you run your java process from ? *That's where it needs to be*.

e.g.

```
$ cd /mydir
$ java com.whatever.TestJava
```

In the above your `.mp3` file needs to be in the `/mydir` directory

Comment: File not found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.main(test.java:19)

Well, here's the exception.

Comment: Your NPE likely comes from if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) with a null mp3file

Comment: @Torcellite uncomment the printStackTrace line and tell us what appears.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found dom.mp3
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.init(FileWrapper.java:26)
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.<init>(FileWrapper.java:19)
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:53)
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:41)
 at test.main(test.java:13)
File not found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.main(test.java:19)


The mpatric package is 3rd party. I'm guessing that works fine.

What do you mean by "same directory as you run your java process from"? Can you give me a for instance, please?

Comment: you can not access the mp3file.getId3v1Tag() when mp3file is null. You should put it in your try block.

Comment: Just pointing out multiple exception type handling capability only works on Java SE 7

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the update. I've already placed it in the same folder. Thing is, I wrote a small FileReader program and tested it on cmd in the same dir. Worked like a charm. Put the same thing in Eclipse and I have multiple exceptions. Any idea why?

Comment: Solved it!

System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

Pasted that into my code, found out the root dir. Apparently it's on the same level as the src and bin folders. Pasted the file there and  it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @BrianAgnew, you should dump your Exception.

**UPDATE**
Try this and select your file you want to use:

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Mp3File mp3file = null;
    try {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        int fileResult = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (fileResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String path = jfc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            mp3file = new Mp3File(path);
            if (mp3file!=null && mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
            ID3v1 id3v1Tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
            System.out.println("Track: " + id3v1Tag.getTrack());
            System.out.println("Artist: " + id3v1Tag.getArtist());
            System.out.println("Title: " + id3v1Tag.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Album: " + id3v1Tag.getAlbum());
            System.out.println("Year: " + id3v1Tag.getYear());
            System.out.println("Genre: " + id3v1Tag.getGenre() + "("+id3v1Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")");
            System.out.println("Comment: " + id3v1Tag.getComment());
          } else {
            System.out.println("The mp3 file does not exists or does not have a ID3v1Tag");
          }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedTagException | InvalidDataException | IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You got rid of all exceptions but the null pointer.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.main(test.java:13)

Comment: have a look on my other comment. You can not access the mp3file.getId3v1Tag() when mp3file is null. You should put it in your try block.

Comment: Yeah, I switched it to the try block. Thing is, my path for the file itself is null. How do I get the path for the mp3 file? Or rather do I have to place it in some specific directory in the project?

Comment: place your mp3 in the .../your-project/fx/dom.mp3 and change to getResource("fx/dom.mp3").getPath()

Comment: if your project is a maven project, you should place it under src/main/resources/audio

Comment: I'm using junit4.11.jar mp3agic is supported. I created a folder "fx" and placed "dom.mp3" in it. The path is in the program is still null.

Comment: OK, place your file in the /src and change the code to:
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("dom.mp3");
mp3file = new Mp3File(url.getPath());

Comment: That caused the same exceptions again.

I tried this.
String myPath = Mp3File.class.getResource("C:\\Users\\Torcellite\\Desktop\\Android apps\\mp3 extractor\\src\\dom.mp3").getPath();
   System.out.println(myPath);
   mp3file = new Mp3File(myPath);

Null pointer exception again though..

Comment: NO, you can not use Mp3File.class.getResource(..) because the resource will be prefixed with the package name. If the file is under src/, then you need to use ClassLoader.getSystemResource("dom.mp3").getPath(); to search under your directory for the file.

Comment: Sorry, I saw my mistake../C:/Users/Torcellite/Desktop/Android%20apps/mp3%20extractor/bin/dom.mp3
File not found.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found /C:/Users/Torcellite/Desktop/Android%20apps/mp3%20extractor/bin/dom.mp3
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.init(FileWrapper.java:26)
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.FileWrapper.<init>(FileWrapper.java:19)
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:53)
 at com.mpatric.mp3agic.Mp3File.<init>(Mp3File.java:41)
 at test.main(test.java:18)


The located path is correct. Why am I still getting errors though?

Comment: Why is there a leading slash on your path? if the Path starts with C:/ i don't think this is right. The path is not correct. If it would, it won't throw a FileNotFoundException ;-)

Comment: I'm printing the myPath string, and that's the path the java program retrieved. :| all that mpatric did in his documentation to declare the file was "Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");"

Comment: Okay, since you said the URL was wrong because of the first slash, I removed that using substring and set the file's path to the new string obtained. I still receive the errors though.

Comment: It didn't work. Still get the same exceptions. Did it work for you? Also, I put the mp3 file in bin and src.

Comment: I tried it with a text file called test.txt and placed it in src and it worked for me. I don't know why it does not find your file?

Comment: Hold on, I'll try with a text file.

Comment: Could you paste your version? i.e the text file version.

Comment: String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.txt").getPath();
File file = new File(path);
I get no exception and file is not null. my test.txt is under /src/main/java

Comment: Wow, even text files aren't recognized. I'm guessing Eclipse is hindering it somehow?

Comment: do you have a default java project in eclipse and only a folder src?